# Designed reports and view them in ASP.NET Core 6.0 web app and Flutter app

Tags: flutter, asp.net-core, reporting-services, .net-6.0

I'm developing an app where clients can design custom reports (ex. invoice) view them in an ASP.NET Core 6.0 web app and Flutter apps (Android, iOS, Windows).

What are the recommended packages that are supported in both ASP.NET Core 6.0 web app and Flutter apps (Android, iOS, Windows)?

Thanks

Comment: why not include flutter web in this as well, instead of an asp.net app, which does not share packages with flutter

Comment: @CStark our current backend is developed with .net core and it's a large admin system not like the flutter mobile apps.